# Extracting the audio from a device and display it in a listview fails

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to display all the audio device of a device in a list view. The app throws an exception on opening. **All the catch statements are being executed**

**LogCat Messages**

```
07-31 22:58:46.131 3100-3100/prakhar.mediacontentprovider E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10058: Read-only file system
07-31 22:58:46.131 3100-3100/prakhar.mediacontentprovider W/Zygote: createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
07-31 22:58:46.131 3100-3100/prakhar.mediacontentprovider I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
07-31 22:58:46.195 3100-3108/prakhar.mediacontentprovider I/art: Debugger is no longer active
07-31 22:58:46.307 3100-3100/prakhar.mediacontentprovider W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
07-31 22:58:46.467 3100-3113/prakhar.mediacontentprovider W/art: Suspending all threads took: 12.472ms
```

```
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.provider.MediaStore; 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView songsList;
    private ArrayList<String> songRows = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdpt;
    private int name, length;
    private Cursor cur;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        songsList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.songslist);

        String[] requestColumns = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION};
        try {
             cur = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, requestColumns, null, null, null);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
             Toast.makeText(this, "Unknown Exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        try{
            name = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            length = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Null Pointer Exception",     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        try{
            cur.moveToFirst();
            while(!cur.isAfterLast()) {
                songRows.add("Title "+cur.getString(name)+" Duration "+cur.getInt(length));
                cur.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        arrayAdpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, songRows);
        songsList.setAdapter(arrayAdpt);
    }
}
```

On opening, the app throws an exception. What is wrong with this Code?

Comment: could you edit the question to include the exception?

Comment: Please edit the code with the full **logcat** of the error.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't. Emulator is really slow on my computer so as I mentioned before I run it on a physical device. (And I don't have a USB chord with me). Can't provide you the exception in the logcat.

Comment: All the catch Statements are being executed

Comment: `ex.printStackTrace()`... Don't just Toast a random string